# Laravel Mail:queue not taking value from env

Tags: laravel, email

> **Not taking value of env `MAIL_HOST` while sending email**

Please describe why this happen ?

```
 try {
     Mail::to([
         [
             'email' => 'abcdef@gmail.com',
             'name'  => 'ABCD',
         ],
     ])->queue(new SendHTMLEmail([
             'subject' => "For A Purpose",
             'body'    => '',
     ]));
 } catch (\Exception $e) { }
```

Comment: How are you accessing `MAIL_HOST` from your `.env` config. I don't see any line accessing that ...

Comment: its in my markdown view that i rendering into emails

Comment: mailer reads from `config/mail.php` where it access the `.env` as `env('MAIL_HOST')`. Check that file if that is accessing the info from the right location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a queue worker, make sure that you do the following two things whenever you update your application configuration (`.env` included):

1. Restart your queue worker(s). Code changes, and also configuration changes, are only picked up by the queue workers when they are restarted.
2. If you are running in production or, for some other reason, you have your configuration cached (with `php artisan config:cache`), then you'll also have to re-cache the configuration with the same command *before restarting your queue worker(s)*.

Answer (score 0):

This should be available in your .env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=
MAIL_PORT=
MAIL_USERNAME=
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=
```

config/mail.php

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
```

These two files make sure that you have entered credentionals.

Also run,

```
php artisan config:cache

php artisan queue:restart
```